# Security steps to be taken care while file uploads, as its said to be vulnerable when kept in root?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, open-source

I have been going through the file uploads through various tutorials and sources, found that uploading into root or any folder which is web accessible is a security issue and is advisable to keep the upload folder outside the root.

Now, if someone is on shared hosting server like **Godaddy**, the user will not be having access outside the root folder.

And if really nothing can be done, how these open source software like Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal keep their uploads securely, and almost very much sure about the security?

The thing is what all has to be taken care, to save data securely on web when the condition is that, we only have option to keep our files within root.

Few checklist which i know for secure file uploads when you are forced to keep your files within the public accessible area are as follows:-

1. Functions to Check Uploaded File Size and Type.
2. While storing files rename the file to some random names and track the filename through database, md5 and sha1 is great.
3. Disable Script Execution with .htaccess.

---

*This is an example for calling the uploaded files:-*

```
    // this is just example only to show how we can get the files

    $imgfile = $rsPhoto['photo']; // or value from database 

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imgfile); 

    switch ($type)
    { 

    case 1: $im = imagecreatefromgif($imgfile);
    header("Content-type: image/gif");
    break; 

    case 2:
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    break; 

    case 3:
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($imgfile);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    break; 

    }
```

---

This is an example, it is not about saving few image files and retrieving it, the data's as we all know categorized in crucial elements of any business success.. so when such kinds of critical and important data has to be handled, what all options we have to make things perfect and secure as possible?

**References:-**

- [Implementing Secure File Upload in PHP](http://corpocrat.com/2007/11/28/implementing-secure-file-upload-in-php/)

---

**EDIT 1:**

Is it a good idea to permanently redirect the domain to a sub folder of your domain...

So that your root is `/` but after redirection your root is `/main-website/`.

So if i keep my upload folder in `/upload/`, i think it will be assumed as outside the web accessible/public area...??

Hence my domain `www.xyz.com` points to `/main-website/`, And the upload folder is out of the scope of this domain...

Just a thought came to my mind so putting it up

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the uploaded files must be World readable. I will assume too that the file can be of any type: pdf, images (pdf, png, ico), documents (docx, xls), etc

The **best solution** here (generic that not just applies for PHP projects, but web projects in general) **is to add a layer of complexity or a layer of redirection**: You will save the file with a custom name self generated in the server, and use a BBDD to store the original file name.

Ok, let's see it by example. Imagine we have this directories:

```
/ -> Root. Its World Readable
/files -> Where we will store your files. World Readable too.
```

So, when I upload a file to your site named "foo.png", you will save it to "/files" directory, but  you must change the name of my file to a auto generated one[1]. Let's say "1234asd". You must write in a BBDD a new record with the old file name ("foo.png") with the new auto-generated one. So... now, ¿how can I download my file if I don't know the new name?

Well, you must create "/file.php" in you server, that will accept GET parameter called "filename". Then I can do: "/file.php?filename=foo.png" and your code will do the follow:

- Search in the BBDD if the file "foo.png" exists. If exists, get the name of the real filename. If not exist just return a 404 HTTP Code.
- Then read the file from the **direcory** "/files/1234asd" and return it to the user

This way, **any kind of files can be uploaded to you server** (*.php files too), **and you are secured, because the files are not accessed directly, but throw you PHP code** (file.php).

This offers additional advantages like being able to check if a user have permission to read the file he is requesting (by implementing some kind of simple authentication). If the file is not found instead of return a ugly 404 HTTP code (that it's the correct stuff to do in that case) you can return a custom error message saying "ooops! 404 - The file you request is not available" or something like that.

Note: this solution applies to a files from 0 to maybe.... 10MB-20MB. If you are working with larger files, this solution is not optimal, and another approach should be take.

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to (the google cached text only version) an article that is useful in helping secure wordpress.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:V5RddpaOH4IJ:gerry.ws/2008/10/152/setup-and-secure-your-wordpress-upload-directory.html&hl=en&gl=au&strip=1

(i've linked to the google cache version becuase their site makes my chrome/firefox lock up, text only doesn't).

Basically you put your uploads in a location that only the app can access it (above or outside the web location) and then:

- limiting the mimetypes of file that can be uploaded (and validating the files to make sure they don't contain known buffer overruns, exploits like exif poisining, embedded executables, etc)
- make sure you aren't allowing parent paths
- make sure that your upload path calculation is run server side not through some sort of hidden form field etc
- make sure the execute access of your server platform (e.g. php/apache) won't execute in that location
- make sure that only the web server (e.g. apache) account has rights to write to the location
- make sure your scripts validate the data being posted in the upload

see also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Beside the methods to check file while upload it to your server like: check extension/mimetype, limit upload size... I have more tips bellow.

When I use shared hosting : turn off php execution in upload folder, you can use htaccess with php_flag=off.

When I have dedicated server: Setup a storage without any script(php) execution and upload file via ftp.

Answer (score 1):

While you may not have access to any other folder outside root, typically on shared hosting you have access to your home directory.
I have tested on a server I have, and I can store files on /home/myuser which may be outside webroot (typically located in /home/youruser/www).
Also, you can use /tmp which is writtable for everyone, but if you do so, do not store sensitive data there, as it is readable by all users of hoster.